# Search up CSV values in cell in table via vlookup and apply values

Tags: excel, csv, vlookup

Let's say I have the following table:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWHFy.png

In a different table, I have a column with comma-separated values of the deduction numbers that apply: (E.g. 1, 4, 6).

How can I vlookup all of the corresponding deduction number point values and sum them up?

For instance, if the cell said 7, 1 , and 2a, it would sum up -15, -5, and -2 for a total of -22.

Examples: https://i.stack.imgur.com/14qzS.png

(Note: I do not have enough reputation to post images, so if anyone would be as benevolent as to edit the post and add the images, I'd appreciate it.)

Comment: If there's a reasonably small number of values per cell, you can use Text-To-Columns to split into individual cells, then sum up the vlookup results for each of those cells.

Comment: ^.....Otherwise, VBA may make this take easier from a user standpoint

Comment: Could you clarify how one table is related to the other? it'd be better if you include in your images cells headers so it's easier to understand what you're refering to.

Comment: @urdearboy I'd be open to a VBA solution.

Comment: @RicardoDiaz I'm not quite sure I understand. The title for each column is at the top of the images. The first image has the numbers that correspond to each deduction and their corresponding values. The second image has cells with a CSV-style of the deduction numbers, which are used to get the deduction values that will be summed up in the column to its right.

Comment: @CharlesBenz now I got it. Was somehow confusing because you have another cell highlighted in the image. Please check my answer bellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work convert the data you have to Excel structured tables (Backup your workbook, select the data and press "Ctrl" + "T", assign a name to the table)
Check this for further reference:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c

In essence you should have two tables as this:
 - Table that holds the deduction points (I'm calling it TableDeduction)
 - Table that holds the Typical deduction number (I'm calling it TableTypical)

Copy and paste this code into a module and customize every row bellow the text >>>> Customize:

```
Sub GetPoints()

    ' Declare objects variables
    Dim typicalTable As ListObject
    Dim deductionTable As ListObject
    Dim typicalCell As Range

    ' Declare other variables
    Dim sheetName As String
    Dim typicalTableName As String
    Dim deductionTableName As String
    Dim typicalValues As Variant ' Array
    Dim deductionValue As Integer ' Change for long if sum is gonna be greater than 32.000

    ' Generic variables
    Dim counter As Integer


    ' >>>> Customize to fit your needs
    sheetName = "Sheet1"
    typicalTableName = "TableTypical"
    deductionTableName = "TableDeduction"
    ' <<<<

    ' Initiate table objects
    Set typicalTable = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetName).ListObjects(typicalTableName)
    Set deductionTable = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetName).ListObjects(deductionTableName)

    ' Loop through the typical table cells
    For Each typicalCell In typicalTable.DataBodyRange.Columns(1).Cells

        ' Validate that it's valid
        If typicalCell.Value <> "None" Then

            ' Reinitiate the sum
            deductionValue = 0

            ' Split to cell values by commas
            typicalValues = Split(typicalCell.Value, ",")

            ' For each value look it's corresponding deduction points
            For counter = 0 To UBound(typicalValues)

                ' >>>> Customize the columns number

                If IsError(Application.Match(CStr(typicalValues(counter)), deductionTable.DataBodyRange.Columns(1), 0)) Then

                    ' >>>> Customize the columns number

                    ' Lookup the table for numbers
                    If IsNumeric(Application.Index(deductionTable.DataBodyRange.Columns(2), Application.Match(CLng(typicalValues(counter)), deductionTable.DataBodyRange.Columns(1), 0))) Then

                        ' >>>> Customize the columns number

                        deductionValue = deductionValue + Application.Index(deductionTable.DataBodyRange.Columns(2), Application.Match(CLng(typicalValues(counter)), deductionTable.DataBodyRange.Columns(1), 0))
                    End If
                Else
                    ' >>>> Customize the columns number

                    ' Lookup the table for string
                    If IsNumeric(Application.Index(deductionTable.DataBodyRange.Columns(2), Application.Match(CStr(typicalValues(counter)), deductionTable.DataBodyRange.Columns(1), 0))) Then

                        ' >>>> Customize the columns number

                        deductionValue = deductionValue + Application.Index(deductionTable.DataBodyRange.Columns(2), Application.Match(CStr(typicalValues(counter)), deductionTable.DataBodyRange.Columns(1), 0))
                    End If
                End If

                ' Output the value in the next cell
                typicalCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = deductionValue

            Next counter

        End If

    Next typicalCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Would TableDeduction contain both the deduction numbers and points or just the points?

Comment: Both columns yes, and remeber that both tables have headers

Comment: Also, would TableTypical also have the column to the right where the sum is supposed to go or just the "Typical deduction numbers"?

Comment: You can add it (I named it: Total deduction points in my dev) but you can add the header you want